# How do I formulate a query using a sub Object as a field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I formulate a query that uses a **sub Object** field to return a cursor?

My Object structure looks like this:

```
_id: "4ncBGvppEs92e4tcZ"
expiryDate: "2017-05-27T21:45:57+03:00"
viewStatisticsArray: Array[1]
     0: Object
           nrOfViews:155
           statesDate:"Fri Mar 24 2017 12:46:21 GMT+0300 (EAT)"
           viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy"
```

Please note that the `viewedBy` *(also what I am refering to as a Sub Object)* value carries my user id generated from `Meteor.user()._id;`

```
var MyUserId = Meteor.user()._id;
```

I have unsucessfully tried:

```
Db.find({},{viewedBy: { $in: MyUserId } } ).fetch();
```

Also unsucessfully tried:

```
Db.find({},{viewStatisticsArray.viewedBy: { $in: MyUserId } } ).fetch();
```

Please help! How do I forumlate the query above correctly? 
The expected results should yeild in a cursor full of Objects that only have viewedBy: "udEnfEmy5DSBvDsSy".

Comment: Can you try `Db.find({'viewStatisticsArray.viewedBy': { $in: [ MyUserId ] } } ).fetch();` ?

Answer (score 1):

In mongodb (and therefore Meteor), the correct way to execute this type of query is to use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents) operator.  As an example, your query would look like this.

```
Db.find({
  viewStatisticsArray: {
    $elemMatch: {
      viewedBy: MyUserId 
    }
  }
});
```

Since, however, you are only needing to specify a single query predicate, you can alternatively use the below query as well.

```
Db.find({
  'viewStatisticsArray.viewedBy': MyUserId 
});
```

One word of caution, I don't know if minimongo (the mongodb like db that runs on the client in a meteor app) support the `$elemMatch` operator.  If that is the case, and if you are executing this query on the client, then you must use the 2nd option above.

Comment: `$elemMatch` is supported in minimongo.